# how to display records as empty if data not present in table using left join

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

```
SELECT MH.Home_Address_Id,MH.Member_Id,MH.First_Name,MH.Middle_Name,
       MH.Last_Name,MH.Address AS Preferred_Address,MH.City AS Preferred_City,
       MH.State AS Preferred_State,MH.Zip ASPreferred_Zip,MH.Nickname,
       MH.Phone,MH.Mobile,MH.Email,
       (CASE WHEN MH.Preferred=0 THEN 'Work Address' 
             WHEN MH.Preferred=1 THEN 'Home Address' END)AS Preferred,
       (CASE WHEN MP.Status=0 THEN 'Current'
             WHEN MP.Status=1 THEN 'Past due' 
             WHEN MP.Status=2 THEN 'Paid' END)AS Status,
       MP.Payment_Amount,MP.Payment_Date,MT.Admiral_Title,MT.Spouse_Title,
       MT.Couple_Title,MS.First_Name AS Spouse_name,
       MS.Nickname AS Spouse_Nickname, 
       MS.Email AS Spouse_Email,sca.SubCategory_Name AS Admiral_Type_Id, 
       scr.SubCategory_Name AS Royalty_Type_Id,
       scp.SubCategory_Name AS Parent_Type_Id,
       scg.SubCategory_Name AS Guest_Type_Id,
       MM.Member_Note, g.Guest_Name AS Guest_Of
FROM
member_home_address MH,
member_payment_master MP,
member_mailing_title MT,
member_spouse_info MS,
member_master MM,
LEFT JOIN guest g ON g.Member_Id = MM.Member_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory sca ON sca.SubCategory_Id = MM.Admiral_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory scr ON scr.SubCategory_Id = MM.Royalty_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory scp ON scp.SubCategory_Id = MM.Parent_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory scg ON scg.SubCategory_Id = MM.Guest_Type_Id
WHERE MH.Member_Id IN
(1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,29,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41 ,44,45,46,47,48,49,52,53,55,57,58,59,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,75,76,78,80,81,
87,88,89,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,106,107,108,109,111,113,115,116,117,
118,119,121,122,123,124,128,129,130,131,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,143,145,146,148,
149,150,151,152,153,155,156,158,159,160,163,164,166,167,169,170,171,172,173,174,177,179,180,
181,182,183,185,186,187,189,191,192,193,194,196,198,199,202,205,206,209,210,211,212,213,214,
217,218,219,221,222,223,224,227,228,229,231,234,235,236,238,239,240,243,245,246,247,248,249,
251,252,253,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,274,275,277,
280,281,284,285,286,287,289,290,291,292,294,295,296,298,300,301,302,303,304,305,307,308,310,
311,313,314,315,316,318,320,321,322,323,324,325,327,328,331,332,334,336,337,338,339,341,343,
344,345,346,347,348,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,361,931,934,935,936,937,938,939,
940,941,942,944,945,946,947,948,950,951,952,1431,1432,1433,1434,1435,1436,1437,1438,1439,144
0,1441,1442,1443,1444,1445,1446,1447,1448,1449,1450,1451,1452,1453,1454,1455,1986,1987,1988,
1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,3168,3164,3142,3143,3144,3154,3155,3156,3157,3158,
3159,3160,3161,3162,3165,3167)
    AND MH.Member_Id = MP.Member_Id
    AND MH.Member_Id = MT.Member_Id
    AND MP.Member_Id = MS.Member_Id
    AND MP.Member_Id = MM.Member_Id
```

here for the member_id '10' we don't have record in the member_spouse_info table.It is skipping the total member_id. How can we get the data of member_id 10.using the above query? Why is it omitting certain rows?

Comment: use IFNULL function in the projection... Ex : 
IFNULL(columnName,'')

Comment: Here member_id with "10" record is not present in the member_spouse_info table.problem is not with the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unfortunately combining the old-time list-of-tables / WHERE id=id syntax with the newer and more effective `LEFT JOIN` syntax.

```
 FROM member_home_address MH,  ...
      member_spouse_info MS ...
WHERE ... MH.Member_Id = MS.Member_Id
```

is the equivalent of an INNER JOIN. So, the absent record in `MS` is suppressing the whole result set record.

You want this instead

```
FROM member_master MM
LEFT JOIN member_payment_master MP ON MM.Member_Id = MP.Member_Id
LEFT JOIN member_mailing_title MT ON MM.Member_Id = MT.Member_Id
LEFT JOIN member_spouse_info MS ON MM.Member_Id = MS.Member_Id
LEFT JOIN member_home_address MH ON MM.Member_Id = MH.Member_Id
LEFT JOIN guest g ON g.Member_Id = MM.Member_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory sca ON sca.SubCategory_Id = MM.Admiral_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory scr ON scr.SubCategory_Id = MM.Royalty_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory scp ON scp.SubCategory_Id = MM.Parent_Type_Id
LEFT JOIN member_subcategory scg ON scg.SubCategory_Id = MM.Guest_Type_Id
```

Then, get rid of these WHERE clauses. You've moved them into the LEFT JOIN syntax. If you leave them in place they convert the LEFT JOIN operations into INNER JOIN operations.

```
AND MH.Member_Id = MP.Member_Id  /*delete these!*/
AND MH.Member_Id = MT.Member_Id
AND MP.Member_Id = MS.Member_Id
AND MP.Member_Id = MM.Member_Id
```

I started this join list with `member_master` on the assumption that it actually contains one row for each member, and should drive the rest of the join.

Your query, for some reason I don't know, selects the rows and drives the JOIN cascade based on the rows in `member_home_address`.  You may want to try driving it with

```
WHERE MM.Member_ID IN (/*dirty great list of member ids*/)
```

instead.

If I were you I'd troubleshoot this query by building it up join table by join table. You're the only one in possession of the data; StackOverflow can't help you find missing records.

Comment: Thanks For the reply @Ollie Jones.
Iam Still getting the same result where member_id with 10 records not present.I forgot to tell you that same member_id info is not present in guest table too.

Comment: In where condition also we are checking the id 
    AND MP.Member_Id = MS.Member_Id.
which always fails if record 10 in MS table is not present